# Alert Manager won't start but Prometheus starts fine

Tags: docker, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to start prometheus and alert manager using docker.

However, when running docker-compose up I hit this error:

```
msg="Loading configuration file failed" 
file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml err="open 
/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml: no such file or directory"
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'

services:

prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    privileged: true
    volumes:
        - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
        - ./alertmanager:/alert.rules
    command:
        - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
        - '9090:9090'

node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    ports:
        - '9100:9100'

alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    privileged: true
    volumes:
         - ./alertmanager:/etc/alertmanager/
    command:
        - --config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
    ports:
        - '9093:9093'
```

alertmanager.yaml

```
global:
slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/eufiwbhfgvehjvfeyvfhevhfvey

route:
  receiver: 'slack'

receivers:
  - name: 'slack'
    slack_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        username: 'alert'
        channel: '#wgeygyhvdwvy'
```

Prometheus and node-exporter both and runs fine, the file structure for Alertmanager matches Prometheus so can't see where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alertmanager is complaining that it can't find `alertmanager.yml` but you mention the name of your file being `alertmanager.yaml`. (The file name suffix: `yml` vs `yaml`.)

Comment: unbelievable error on my part, can tell i've never used .yml before!